# Change button using CSS or by using scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using data tables to show data and a button is present opposite to each entry of my data table.

That button has onclick which captures the parameter present in a row and save in array.

I want to change color when certain entry is selected and reset on deselect.

Here is what I am doing,

```
function select(name){
        var property = document.getElementById('checkRule');
        if( rArray.includes(name) ){
            
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            const index = rArray.indexOf(name);
              if (index > -1) {
                  rArray.splice(index, 1);
              }
            
        }else{
            rArray.push(name);
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#28a0ff"
        }
        
        console.log('ARRAY >> ', rArray);
    }
```

This code is only changing color of very first element of of data table.

How shall I make it work?

Comment: This isn't Java.

Comment: `$("#form")` matches an element with `id="form"` but you don't have that in the HTML.

Comment: @GuyIncognito.. I tried that too.. aint working

Comment: how does you ajax get called ? on click of some button ?

Comment: @Swati.....  YES

Comment: "Ain't working" isnt' enough information to tell what's wrong. You need to show what you have and what the console.logs print.

Comment: I think that serializeArray will only work if submit event happen. You can also get your radio button value directly

Comment: Problem 1: as already mentioned, `$("#form")` does not match anything, so all the various variables created are all empty. Problem 2: The AJAX will run on page load, like all the other JS.  Typically it would happen on form submission, or on a click, etc, but in this case it is executed on load.  So even after problem 1 is fixed, the AJAX will fire on page load before there is any selection or interaction on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to send the ajax request after you select a radio button and you click on *go*.

You do not need to change the html, but you will have to change the javascript file.

```
$("#go").click(() => {
  var result = $("input:radio[name='doamin']:checked").val();

  console.log("result > ", result);

  var Data = {
    result1: result,
  };

  console.log("postData > ", Data);

  $.ajax({
    url: "import",
    headers: {
      Accept: "text/plain",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: JSON.stringify(Data),
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
});
```

Ideally, you want to send a POST request, as there is a body attached.